# Owl carousel V1 disable/enable drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, owl-carousel

Hey all I have a quick question regarding the [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/).

How can I enable the **touchdrag** when I first use this code:

```
var owl = $(".full-slider");

owl.owlCarousel({
        slideSpeed              : 500,
        singleItem              : true,
        pagination              : false,
        autoPlay                : false,
        afterMove               : slideChanged,
        startDragging           : pauseOnDragging,
        touchDrag               : false,
        mouseDrag               : false
});
```

Depending on the options the user uses on my page, I want to disable the ability to drag to the next slide. But if the user completes the options then I would like to enable it back so they can drag to the next slide.

How can this be done? I haven't been able to find a good example online for doing this.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I found out how to do it finally:

```
 owl.data('owlCarousel').reinit({
     touchDrag  : true,
     mouseDrag  : true
 });
```

Comment: Code works. I found that reinit() will reset the slider to the first slide.

Comment: i should be capital in reinit. It should be reInit()